# .net regular error exception The model backing the newvalidContext context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working in C# and I'm having an issue after changes in model like regular expression.

I'm getting the following error:

> [image]

The model backing the 'newvalidContext' context has changed since the
  database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
  the database (go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change something in your Model you have to migrate it so that the changes also apply in the database. *"first you drop and delete your old migration"*

then you need to enter:

dotnet ef migrations add init1

then:

dotnet ef database update

Comment: I have tried in package manageer console command like  Update-migration  but still having same issue

Comment: Try `add-migration <migrationname>`, then `update-database`. You might need to run `enable-migrations` if you haven't done so already.